# Sending SMS in twilio returns 21603 : A 'From' number is required

Tags: sms, twilio

This is a regular funded account - It will insist there is no From Number - I also tried as request parameters rather than request body, SID and TOKEN are correct, tested by modifying them and getting appropriate error. Works fine with the twilio libraries, not as a standalone POST

```
POST /2010-04-01/Accounts/ACCOUNT_SID/Messages.json HTTP/1.1
Host: ACCOUNT_SID:AUTH_TOKEN@api.twilio.com
Content-Type: text/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ "body": "Jenny please?! I love you <3", "From": VALID_TWILIO_NUMBER, "to": MY_CELL }
```

Also I would like to specify the ACCOUNT_SID and AUTH_TOKEN as header parameters, but Twilio does not recognize them.

Answer (score 3):

The following works (from POSTMAN history)

```
POST /2010-04-01/Accounts/ACCOUND_SID/Messages.json HTTP/1.1
Host: api.twilio.com
Authorization: Basic Base64_encoding(ACCOUNT_SID:AUTH_TOKEN)
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body=%22Test+1+-+urlencoded%22&From=%22%2BVALID_TWILIO_NUMBER%22&To=%22%2BMY_CELL%22
```

A few observations:
   This worked using POSTMAN in Chrome and HTTPRequester in Firefox (Authorization entered interactively through user/passwd dialog)

The Body, From, and To parameters MUST be spelled that way, if the first letter is lowercase, it will return the above error or similar.

That was the only Content-Type that worked - could not get it to work with a JSON request body (the way I posed it on the original question) - that remains an open issue.

Comment: Brilliant answer, concerning the 'Body' part. Have been searching for hours to get this right. Thanks for this tip. BTW, the following works as well: Body="Test+1+-+urlencoded"&From="%2BVALID_TWILIO_NUMBER"&To="%2BMY_CELL". Every %22 replaced by double quotes. So the essence was in the %2B in stead of the + sign.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use request parameters:

```
$ curl -XPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659/Messages.json \
    -d "Body=Jenny%20please%3F%21%20I%20love%20you%20<3" \
    -d "To=%2B15558675309" \
    -d "From=%2B14158141829" \
    -d "MediaUrl=http://www.example.com/hearts.png" \
    -u 'AC5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659:{AuthToken}'
```

Additionally, I have seen that "No From Parameter" error when the phone number is not properly formatted.

Comment: I have been trying a variation of this cURL command but I keep getting a  "The 'To' number +[redacted] is not a valid phone number." This number (I redacted it in this comment) is my own cell phone and I am using that same cell number in the "From." Why would Twilio return this error message if I know for a fact that the "To" value is a valid phone number?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this with Twilio's new WhatsApp messaging and was running into the same issue. Content-type was important, but also how the body of the POST request was formatted.

```
From=whatsapp:%2B441618507453&To=whatsapp:%2B17796758684&Body=Your appointment is coming up on {{July 21}} at {{3PM}}
```

Note the use of URL encoding for "+" symbols