# Can't send SMS message with test credentials and Rest Console in chrome

Tags: rest, sms, twilio

I am using the correct test accound sid and auth token. The params entered are From, To, and Body like so:

> Request Url:
>   https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{mytestaccoundsid}/SMS/Messages
>   Request Method: POST Status Code: 400 Params: {
>       "From": "+15005550001",
>       "To": "+15005550002",
>       "Body": "Testing" }

For some reason it keeps saying "A 'From' phone number is required." This error is not one of the expected errors listed:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials

Comment: The number you are using is considered "invalid" by the test creds, have you tried using the number ```+15005550006``` to see if that works?

Comment: Yes, I have tried several different numbers they list on the test-credentials page. As well I have also tested real numbers. All return the same response. My understanding is the test numbers should return the specific error code listed. So the error code should have been 21421 but it returns 21603 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I talked with their tech support and they support JSON encoded parameters but they to could not get it to work. Looks like its a bug on their part.

Answer (score 0):

[Sending SMS in twilio returns 21603 : A 'From' number is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617722/sending-sms-in-twilio-returns-21603-a-from-number-is-required)

The above link solved the same problem for me. Check it out. The key is that you have to use urlencoded parameters